# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just started Android Studio for the first time and made a new project with the default name and everything just to start. But it gives an error in my `MainActivity.java`.

```
Cannot Resolve symbol 'R'
```

This is the code where it gives error:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Can anyone tell what is this 'R' it is looking for?

Comment: Before starting coding first study about the basic concepts of Android and also search for `What is R.java in Android`.

Comment: Looks like a gradle sync error. Can you press the button "Sync Gradle Files", (should be somewhere in the action bar)

Comment: Possibility is you have error in your xml file or manifest or Try to press Alt + enter on R.

Comment: any other error? if you have another error that different `cannot Resolve symbol 'R'`. you should fix it first then clean the project

Comment: it means your project missing some sources like layouts or images or strings or any assets please share your logcat.sync once your project

Comment: Is your layout called activity_main that you are wanting to set the content view to? Also put @Override above the protected.

Comment: Hey Guys.. In my project R.java file is not present ..I think that is the problem
isn't is auto generated? what can I do for that?

Comment: James Robert Singleton- Yes the layout is activity_main.xml and @Override is already written above the method

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml files and if any defect(error) found than solve ,
and than build the gradle.

if above lines don't help than 
try this:-
import YOUR PACKAGE NAME(DEFAULT PACKAGE NAME).R;

hope this will Help you, because always it helps me  ;

Answer (score 0):

R.java is auto generated. There are different situation

1. Java is case sensitive. Use "**R**.layout.activity_main"
2. Check your `activity_main.xml`. Any problem of it? (eg: @drawable/login not exist)
3. Clean your project. (AndroidStudio will build itself)

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: @cakan thans for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a result of resource compilation errors. There should be resource compiler (AAPT) errors above this one. Fix these and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Hello!..The issue seems to be that the R.java file is not generated ... can you help with that?

Comment: Look closely at the output produced during the build. You'll find some errors there. Fix them.